# AttributeError : type object 'x' has no attribute 'y'

Tags: python

I know it's a recurring question but I really don't understand why I get this error. So I have a class `World`, which has a class method `newDay()` that increments `_day` by 1. But by doing so I get this attribute error. I have tried to increment this in different ways but I kept getting an error. Here is some of the code:

```
class World:
    SIZE = Size_world
    ZONES = list()

    def __init__(self):
        self.bob = list()
        self.position = None
        self.available_energy = 0
        self._tick = 100
        self._day = 0
    @classmethod
    def newDay(cls):
        cls.destroyFood()
        cls.randomFood()
        cls._tick = D
        cls._day += 1
```

```
from World import *
def ui_simulation():

    Monde = World()
    Monde.initialize_world()

    while Monde._day < 50:

        bob_tab = Bob.BOBS[:]
        ZONES = World.ZONES[:]

        while Monde._tick > 0: # d est la variable qui décompte les ticks dans la journée. Elle va de 100 à 0
            separator = "."
            for i in range(Size_world):
                for j in range(Size_world-1):
                    if len(ZONES[i + j*Size_world].bob) > 0:
                        print("0", end=separator)
                    elif ZONES[i + j*Size_world].available_energy > 0:
                        print("X", end=separator)
                    else:
                        print(" ", end=separator)
                print(".")

            for bob in bob_tab:
                bob.eat()

            Monde._tick -= 1
            Monde.positionate_bob()
            sleep(0.04)
            clear_screen()
        Monde.newDay()
```

So newDay is called once 100 ticks have gone. What I don't understand is that if _day wasn't an attribute of the object World, why don't I get an error when I make the test Monde._day< 50?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What's the exact error with trace?

Comment: Please show us the [actual error message](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). Do not try to paraphrase error messages or try to guess what you think it means.

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'World' has no attribute '_day'
Sorry I tought I had written it.

Comment: @Baroud do you understand the difference between an instance and a class?

Comment: An instance is a "version" of an object. So if my method is a classmethod, I can't access it through an instance? But if I were to do something like World._day += 1, would it increment it for every instance?

Answer (score 0):

The `cls` argument in class methods is the class, not an object of that class. I think you want newDay to just be a regular member function:

```
def newDay(self):
    self.destroyFood()
    self.randomFood()
    self._tick = D
    self._day += 1
```

In other words, `_day` is not a member of the class `World`, it is a member of each `World` object. For reference, in your example, `SIZE` is an attribute of `World` because you have declared it in the class scope.

Edit:
In python you can access class attributes through objects, but not vice-versa. Classes are unaware of their objects, so it would make no sense to be able to access object attributes through the class.

In general, the `@classmethod` decorator is used for class factory methods (i.e. to create and return an object of that class). To modify or retrieve data from an object of that class, use a regular method.

Comment: I seems to work by doing so.
Now I need to really understant what classmethods are and how to use them.
If _day is a member of each World object, it means I can't access it through an instance?

Comment: I've edited my answer with more information. "Instance" is synonymous with "object", so yes, you can access _day through an instance of World.

classmethods are usually used as factory methods (to create and return an instance of that class). This is not what you want to do here.